# How to get build changes (list of commits) in TeamCity?

Tags: git, teamcity

We use TeamCity as CI.

We have a build that runs after each merge to dev branch.

One thing I'm trying to accomplish is how to get the list of changes that were made on that build specially after more than one merge occurred. Since the build takes a lot to run we might end up with more than one merge request merged between each build (I know the consequences of that, but that's not the point here, so please focus on the issue)

For the specific case I'm attaching an image from a TeamCity Changes tab example.

[image]

We have two merges (the top commit is a merge, and the previous commit is too a merge commit even though it doesn't appear that way).

I tried `git log commit_hash^..commit_hash` but unfortunately, with two merges I only get the last tree commits (the one the right). And I would like to have all the changes.

I looked at the TeamCity documentation reference and I did not find anything related to commit changes per build being exposed. I guess they store the last build's id and then work their way into the current one? Or is there a way to figure it out using git alone?

Thank you very much